# How to convert UTF8-hex to ASCII in a JSON file using R?

Tags: r, json, unicode, utf-8

I have a JSON file with french names containing accents:

```
{
         "Name": "Marguerite-Bourgeoys/Th<c3><a9><c3><a2>tre du C<c3><a9>gep (1096)",
        "Site": "CEGEP pavillon des Humanit<c3><a9>s (517)",
}
```

I want these accents, coded in UTF8-hex to be translated to full ASCII.
I went through all the related posts in SO, trying iconv, uni2ascii
but they only return the same text.

This JSON is created with R using the jsonlite library

```
library(jsonlite)
d <- data.frame(Name="Marguerite-Bourgeoys/Théâtre du Cégep (1096)",Site="CEGEP     pavillon des Humanités (517)")
toJSON(d,pretty=T)
```

This output is fine, but if I run this process automatically using daemontools

https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Then the accents are replaced by their hexcodes.
One way out is to convert these hexcodes after the file has been produced.

Comment: Please provide more context about your problem. Does your software generate this strange encoding and you want to fix it? Or does your software consume these JSON data and your looking for code that can handle it? Or what exactly do you want? What programming language, operating system, libraries are you using anyway?

Comment: And by the way: *Marguerite-Bourgeoys/Théâtre du Cégep (1096)* and *CEGEP pavillon des Humanités (517)* cannot be represented in ASCII (or whatever *full ascii* is). You will need another encoding, preferably Unicode based.

Comment: Probably you can convince R to output valid UTF-8 even under daemontools by mucking with settings (presumably locale settings?)

Comment: If not, `perl -pe 's/<(\x{2})>/chr(oct("0x$1"))/ge' file.json` as a separate postprocessing step should hopefully fix the files.

Comment: As a summary, for the sake of operation I just added a sed command within my code, that automatically translates the hexcode into letters with accents. There must be cleverer way to do it I admit but that works.